# T-SQL - Called called the current proc

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there way to tell what proc called the currently executing stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this.

But please... Go [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=124537) and let them know that you want that feature.

EDIT:

I looked into this a little more, and found a potential workaround (ugly to use for this purpose, but it looks like it might be doable):

[SET CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768(SQL.90).aspx)

This is from Books Online:

- Session context information is stored in the context_info column in the master.dbo.sysprocesses table. This is a varbinary(128) column.
- SET CONTEXT_INFO cannot be specified in a user-defined function. You cannot supply a null value to SET CONTEXT_INFO because the sysprocesses table does not allow null values.
- SET CONTEXT_INFO does not accept expressions other than constants or variable names. To set the context information to the result of a function call, you must first place the function call result in a binary or varbinary variable.
- When you issue SET CONTEXT_INFO in a stored procedure or trigger, unlike in other SET statements, the new value set for the context information persists after the stored procedure or trigger completes.

So here's my idea:

add this code to all of your procedures:

```
DECLARE @UID VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @UID = CAST('ThisProcedureName' AS VARBINARY(128))
SET CONTEXT_INFO @UID
```

Then you add this check where you need it:

```
DECLARE @Message varbinary(128)
SELECT @Message = cast('TestB' as varbinary(128))

IF (@Message = CONTEXT_INFO()) BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Not Allowed unless from procedure XX', 16, 1)
END
```

Comment: I posted a tip to my blog including source code: http://www.thecodepage.com/post/TIP-A-Call-Stack-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This question was in the result list when I was researching the same issue, however I found the following code

```
print object_name(@@PROCID)
```

which works a treat within a stored proc, to return the name of the stored proc which contained it. The original article I found at [sql server central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic813548-146-1.aspx).